# Python - Loop to replace elements in string with second element of elements in second string?

Tags: python, list, replace, nlp, append

I am trying to replace elements that are in one string with the second element (also string type) of elements in a second string.

`a_list` and `replace` are short versions of the lists that I am working with. I want to replace the elements in the first list `a_list` with the first elements of each list in the second list, if the second element (POS tags) of each list in the second list matches and then check the rest of the list.

Here is an example part of the lists that I am working with and my not working function:

```
a_list = ["JJ","MM","JJ"]

replace = [['Innovative', 'JJ'],['methods', 'NNS'],['test', 'MM'],['extra', 'JJ']]

new_list = []

for item in a_list:
    if a_list[i] == replace[i][1]:
        new_list.append(item.replace(replace[i][1], replace[i][0]))
        
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)  

['JJ', 'MM', 'JJ']
```

what I want: `['Innovative', "test", "extra"]`

a_list, a_list[1], replace, replace[1], and replace[1][1] are all strings. They were tuples but those were harder for me to work with.

Not sure how to remove that specific string after it was used to replace and not sure how to iterate over both strings. `replace` is a lot longer than `a_list`. I have been working on this for a couple of hours now I'm sure there is something that can do this - just need help, it seems so close! There are many similar questions but I have tried and they have not worked for me

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `i` always zero?

Comment: If you are appending to a new list, there's no need to use `str.replace`, just append the element chosen from the list `replace`.

Comment: i shouldn't always be zero sorry - edited, but if i take it out it gives the same results, i think i had it there when i added 1 each iteration, but I also got stuck there

Comment: What is the desired result for `a_list = ["MM","NNS","JJ"]`?

Comment: the desired result for a_list = ["MM","NNS","JJ"] is new_list=["test","methods","extra"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over `replace` too. If you find a matching entry then add the corresponding value to your list, delete this entry from `replace` and break from the inner loop. If you don't find a match, then add your original item. One of the cases where `for`-`else` comes in handy.

```
a_list = ["JJ","MM","JJ"]
replace = [['Innovative', 'JJ'],['methods', 'NNS'],['test', 'MM'],['extra', 'JJ']]
new_list = []
for item in a_list:
    for i, (value, key) in enumerate(replace):
        if key == item:
            new_list.append(value)
            del replace[i]
            break
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

Result:

```
['Innovative', 'test', 'extra']
```

If you define your list with `a_list = ["Hello", "JJ", "MM", "JJ", "JJ"]` you'll get `['Hello', 'Innovative', 'test', 'extra', 'JJ']`. There is no replacement for `"Hello"` and there's no replacement left for the last `"JJ"`.

Comment: Thank you, Matthias, this worked wonderfully. Super helpful function for NLP with NLTK!!!

Answer (score 0):

The @Matthias answer well responds to the original question. I'd like to suggest a variation to that code using a modification on how the replacements are defined which might be useful in wider use:

```
a_list = ["JJ","MM","JJ"]
new_list = []
replacements = {'JJ': ['Innovative', 'extra'], 'NNS' : ['methods'], 'MM': ['test']}

for item in a_list:
    x = replacements.get(item, None)
    if x and x[0]:
        new_list.append(x[0])
        del x[0]
    else:
        new_list.append(item)
```